# Which is correct — "avoid fight" or "avoid fighting"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, gerunds

> - To avoid **fighting** among children, we should give them equal number of chocolates.
> - To avoid **fight** among children, we should give them equal number of chocolates.

Which one of the above statements is grammatical, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-count-noun categorial polyseme ('incarnation' / usage) of **fight** does exist:

> fight [6] [UNCOUNTABLE] energy and determination to continue trying to
>   achieve something:
>
> After her husband died there was very little fight left in her.
>   [Macmillan]

and arguably in the fixed expression:

> the fight-or-flight response

but the gerund is the only choice that almost all native speakers would make in

'To avoid **fighting** among the children, we should give them an equal number of chocolates'.

Comment: That said - I don't think many native speakers would flinch at 'fight' being pluralized. "To avoid fights among children..." sounds alright to me.

Comment: Yes, but not what OP asked. The count-noun usage would make this general reference, at least on ELU.